# Jhipster user management is not generated automatically

Tags: jhipster

I'm creating a new application with jhipster generator v7.8.1 with the following options:

- Monolithic application
- Spring WebFlux? No
- authentication: OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication
- database: mongodb
- cache: Ehcache
- Maven
- monitor and scale your application? No
- other technologies: Elasticsearch as search engine
- *Framework* for client: React
- Do you want to generate the admin UI? Yes

However, the user management screens are not being generated as they used to be. What could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

There is no user management generated when using OAuth / OIDC. We expect you to manage your users on your identity provider (Keycloak, Okta, or Auth0).